# MySQL Error - Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, create-table

I am new to this SQL and I think I do not understand it fully yet. I am trying to install a script which does the following to insert create tables in a database

The error I get is:

> Error!
>   Mysql entry failed Field 'fb_app_id' doesn't have a default value.

So I searched in the files and found this piece of code which is creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `global_config` (
  `site_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `site_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `site_theme` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fb_app_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fb_app_secret` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fb_app_token` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fb_scope` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tw_app_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tw_app_secret` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `yt_client_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `yt_client_secret` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `yt_dev_token` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `fb_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `tw_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `yt_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ffmpeg` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seo_url` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `media_plugin_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `downloader_plugin_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `image_watermarking_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `video_watermarking_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `image_editor_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `video_editor_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `disable_all_crons` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `disable_poster_cron` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `disable_hide_delete_cron` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `disable_insights_cron` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `disable_videoeditor_bumping_cron` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `enable_signup` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `enable_maintenance_mode` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `maintenance_message` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `paypal_email` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `admin_email` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `site_name` (`site_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

What exactly is causing the issue now and how can I solve it?

All help is appreciated.

EDIT: Index.php

```
$(document).on('click', '.app_setup', function(){

var elem = $(this);
var fb_app_id = $('#fb_app_id').val();
var fb_app_secret = $('#fb_app_secret').val();
var tw_app_id = $('#tw_app_id').val();
var tw_app_secret = $('#tw_app_secret').val();
var yt_client_id = $('#yt_client_id').val();
var yt_client_secret = $('#yt_client_secret').val();
var yt_dev_key = $('#yt_dev_key').val();

elem.hide();
notify('wait', 'Setting up...');
$.post('ajax.php', {
    'fb_app_id': fb_app_id,
    'fb_app_secret': fb_app_secret,
    'tw_app_id': tw_app_id,
    'tw_app_secret': tw_app_secret,
    'yt_client_id': yt_client_id,
    'yt_client_secret' : yt_client_secret,
    'yt_dev_key': yt_dev_key,
    'app_setup': 1
}, function(response){
    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
    if(data.error != ''){
        elem.show();
        return notify('error', data.error);
    }
    else{ 
        notify('success', 'App setup successful');
        $('.step3').slideUp();
        $('.step4').slideDown();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Are you certain that you get this error on creation and not when trying to use the table?

Comment: I don't think that creating a table can generate that error, so there is code you are not including in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited the question and added the coded I found regarding the fb_app_id. Hope this helps. It happens on this website: http://pastebin.com/wdGjpP2u (when pressing next)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the CREATE TABLE statement that is causing the error.

The error is (most likely) from executing an INSERT statement that doesn't supply a value for the column. When a value isn't supplied for a column, MySQL will use the default value for the column.

One option would be to modify the table definition:

```
`fb_app_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'foo',
```

But given the number of other columns in the table that are defined as NOT NULL, that might just move the error to the next column. Without examining the INSERT statement, we're just guessing what "fix" is most appropriate.

---

As a demonstration:

```
CREATE TABLE my_t 
( id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, foo VARCHAR(4)   NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_t (id) VALUES (1); 
-- Error Code: 1364
-- Field 'foo' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO my_t (id,foo) VALUES (2,NULL); 
-- Error Code: 1048
-- Column 'foo' cannot be null

ALTER TABLE my_t CHANGE foo foo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
-- Error Code: 1067
-- Invalid default value for 'foo'

ALTER TABLE my_t CHANGE foo foo VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';

INSERT INTO my_t (id) VALUES (3); 
-- 1 row(s) affected
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited the question and added the coded I found regarding the fb_app_id. Hope this helps.

Comment: It happens on this page when pressing NEXT: http://pastebin.com/wdGjpP2u